# Three JS GLTF exporter resets the u,v to default 1,1 after exporting

Tags: three.js, gltf

I am using three js gltf exporter to convert my scene to a gltf/glb format. everything gets exported nicely except the u,v repeat that i have applied on the texture. i have a view to change the u,v at run time in the application but after exporting they get reset to default 1,1

Comment: This sounds like a bug in the exporter, not setting the correct glTF sampler values.

Comment: I think this is a missing feature in THREE.GLTFExporter, which needs to implement KHR_texture_transform. Consider filing an issue on GitHub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GLTF doesn't really support .repeat since that is a THREE specific design feature.
You can work around it by hand modifying the texture coordinates for the face to simulate the repeat. There may be support in the future via textureMatrix or something, but as far as I know, modifying the UV's is the only way.

Comment: oh i see i thought i was doing something wrong since other run time properties were being applied nicely.
will give it a try.

Comment: another thing you can do with the most recent versions of the gltf export, is save the repeat and offset in the .userData object of the texture, and then re-apply them when you load.

Comment: @manthrax, glTF does indeed support UV repetition.  It's in the [sampler section](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/tree/master/specification/2.0#samplerwraps), and the `REPEAT` setting has an enum value of `10497`.  Here's a [working example](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/blob/2262917421f9b7acdf159350a8247afd11f74343/2.0/TextureSettingsTest/glTF/TextureSettingsTest.gltf#L1035-L1042).

Comment: There is the repeat mode in glTF, but for something like `texture.repeat.set( 4, 4 )`  it requires the glTF KHR_texture_transform extension, which THREE.GLTFExporter doesn't implement. Consider filing an issue on GitHub.